# Symfony 3.3.10 routes

Tags: symfony-3.3

I have problem when i try to use routes. It can't be generated, i tried via /app/config/routes.xml but when i modify i get error that the file is not YAML format.

The controller looks:

```
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

   class MainController extends Controller
   {
   public function indexAction(Request $request)
   {
    return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
}
}
```

When i try to visit /index or main/index it gives me route not found!
:@

Nor works when i put use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route; first before Controller.

Answer (score 2):

- First, you have to put namespace on header.
- Second in Symfony 3.3.10 which route you want to use have to declare before on public function indexAction.

So, your route declaration would be as follows:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
    *@Route("visit/index")
    */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {


        return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', ['base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,]);

    }
}
```